# Is there an equivalent of $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) which will detect NuGet?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

In MSBuild there is a variable $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) which can be used to detect whether build is running inside Visual Studio, so I can do conditions like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true'">
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is there anything similar for NuGet? I want different conditions to run if the project is being used inside package manager.

Comment: I had that question once, and simply made my own.

Comment: For what purpose? I can't imagine a use-case. You want to restore different packages in VS compared to on the command line or a CI agent?

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because my project imports different packages based on conditions. However, when clicking "update" in package manager, it only updates the packages which have a "true" condition at the time, and ignores the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment to the question makes it sound like your goal is to keep a packages versions consistent across different conditions in a single project, but it's also a common case that you want to keep it consistent across projects in a solution or repo.

I'm going to suggest a different solution. Create a [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) in your repo root that looks something like this:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NewtonsoftJsonVersion>12.0.1</NewtonsoftJsonVersion>
    <xunitVersion>2.4.1</xunitVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now in your projects that need Newtonsoft.json, you change the `PackageReference` to `<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="$(NewtonsoftJsonVersion)" />`.

If you put your production code in `src\` and test code in `test\`, then you can create a `test\Directory.Build.props` with the contents:

```xml
<Project>
  <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('Directory.Build.props', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="$(xunitVersion)" />
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now all of your projects under `test\` will get xunit automatically, and it's guaranteed to be the same version.

When you want to upgrade a package version, you can use the Package Manager UI to check for versions, but unfortunately not to upgrade the version. For that, you'll need to manually edit the repo root `Directory.Build.props` (so add it to your solution for quick access), but you can be confident that every reference to that package will use the same version. It is limited to projects using `PackageReference`, there's no solution currently for `packages.config`, but MSBuild conditions only for for `PackageReference` too.

You can see this pattern often in Microsoft repositories. Certainly NuGet (my team, yay!), and various .NET repos like cli and sdk do it, although in manually imported props files, rather than `Directory.Build.props`, though the concept is the same.

Comment: I asked the original question specifically because I wanted to keep the package manager update function working, so unfortunately this isn't a solution.

Comment: @TimBooker in that case, I'm pretty confident that the answer is no. I don't know the package manager UI code very well, but I don't believe we evaluate the MSBuild project setting any properties. In fact, I'm not sure we evaluate the MSBuild project at all, I think we just ask the VS project system for it's state/"view" of the project.

Comment: Well if it’s not exactly possible the way I described, I will accept your solution as the answer as it fixes the consistency problem even though I have to compromise on using package manager to update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution for the case. NuGet is just download manager, it loads sources. MSBuild is a build system, it builds sources. They don't exchange any information between.

I would suggest you to move an another way. You can add a props file into your nuget packaging project with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageUsedFromNuget>true</PackageUsedFromNuget>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```